# Applying scaling and rotation on a view using CGAffineTransform

Tags: objective-c, ios, cgaffinetransform

So I need to apply some scaling and some rotation to a view (I do this using gestures), so for each gesture I update the current scalling and rotation values with something like:

```
self.scaleWidth *= gesture.scale; //When I detect an horizontal pinch
self.scaleHeight *= gesture.scale; //When I detect a vertical pinch
self.rotationAngle += gesture.rotationAngle; //When I detect a rotation
```

Then I do the following to transform the view:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, self.scaleWidth, self.scaleHeight);
self.theSubViewToTransform.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, self.rotationAngle);
```

When I only do scaling, it works fine. When I do scaling then rotate, it rotates fine. When after rotating I try to scale again, it doesn't work fine: the scale is applied as if done after the rotation, deforming my image structure.

I thought I did what needed to be done to avoid this: starting each time from an identity transform, scaling first then rotating, but obviously I was wrong...

Does any one know what's wrong with my implementation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

If you start with the identity transform every time, the end result you are setting the subview's transform to will only include the scaling and rotation from the current gesture. Instead of starting with the identity, start with the current transform of the view.

```
CGAffineTransform transform = self.theSubViewToTransform.transform;
transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, self.scaleWidth, self.scaleHeight);
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, self.rotationAngle);
self.theSubViewToTransform.transform = transform;
```

The first time this executes, the transform will start out as the identity transform. On subsequent executions, it will make the new changes on top of the old ones.

Comment: That's how I did it in the first place, start from previous transform and add the marginal transform each time, but it doesn't help either. If you look at my code you will see that I update my parameters for each tranform with the marginal changes so my parameters are absolute compared to the global view initialization and I should make the transform starting from the identity transform.

Comment: I think the concatenation may be the problem. The recognizers you are using are continuous and will send more than one callback. The scale and rotation factors from the gestures are from the beginning of the gesture, not the change since the last callback. You should not be multiplying by these factors every time the gesture changes. It is hard to tell more, though, without seeing more of your code.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry, my fault. I forgot to mention in my initial post that I reset the recognizer's value at each callback.

Answer (score 7):

For **swift 3**:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:  CGFloat.pi).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.4, y: 0.4))
```

Answer (score 3):

You should start from your current transformed state and apply transformation which is expected. Also you can have a look at `CGAffineTransformConcat`, it will make it a single transform before applying.

```
CGAffineTransform transform = yourView.transform;
transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformScale(transform,  self.scaleWidth, self.scaleHeight),
                                    CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, self.rotationAngle));
yourView.transform = transform;
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try applying the transformations to the identity transform, e.g.

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, angle);
viewToTransform.transform = transform;
```